# Use Hadamard factorization to show that $\cosh(z) = p(z)$ has infinitely many solutions for a polynomial $p$.

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm going over a passed exam paper and the part a is to define Hadamard's Factorisation theorem:

> Let $f$ be entire of order $ρ$ such that $f(0) \neq 0$. Then
> $$f(z) = P(z)e^{Q(z)}
> $$
> where $P(z)$ is the canonical product formed with the zeros of $f$ and $Q(z)$ is a polynomial
> of degree at most $ρ$.

So I assume I will need to use it for part b:

> Let $p(z)$ be a polynomial for which $p(0) \neq 1$. Show that the equation
> $\cosh(z) = p(z)$ has infinitely many solutions.

But $cosh(z)=0$ doesn't exist. How far I've gotten:

$$\cosh(z)=P(z)e^{Q(z)}$$
as $\cosh$ is order 1,  $Q(z)$ is a polynomial of order 1
$$\cosh(z)=P(z)e^{bz}$$

I don't know where to go next.

Comment: $\cosh$ has infinitely many zeros. Note that $\cosh z = \cos (iz)$, thus $\cosh z = 0$ if and only if $z = (k + 1/2)\pi i$ for some $k \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: look up the well known Hadamard factorization of the sine function and get from there to $\cosh$ by 2 substitutions - or one can start from the Hadamard factorization of the cosine and do one substitution  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_factorization_theorem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to show that $\cosh(z) = p(z)$ has infinitely many solutions you need to consider the factorization of $\cosh(z) - p(z)$, not that of $\cosh(z)$.

Assume that there are only finitely many solutions. Then
$$
\cosh(z) - p(z) = \frac 12 (e^z + e^{-z}) - p(z) =  P(z) e^{bz}
$$
with a polynomial $P$ and a constant $b \in \Bbb C$.

If $\operatorname{Re}b \le 0$ this implies that $e^x$ has at most polynomial growth for $x \in \Bbb R$, $x \to + \infty$, which is not possible.

If $\operatorname{Re}b \ge 0$ then you get a similar contradiction for $x \in \Bbb R$, $x \to - \infty$.

Comment: So its because $e^x$ has exponential growth instead of polynomial growth ?

Comment: @Hannah: Yes, the exponential function grows faster than any polynomial.